# Why does Array#shuffle! not work with the nested array?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

Here I was trying to see how `Array#shuffle!` works with array objects. So I started playing with it in my *`IRB`*:

```
[1,2,3]
#=> [1, 2, 3]
[1,2,3].shuffle!
#=> [3, 1, 2]
```

In the above code I understood how it works. And the below I was trying to play with it more hard-way to see it from every corner.

```
[1,2,5]
#=> [1, 2, 5]
[1,2,5]<<[1,2,5]
#=> [1, 2, 5, [1, 2, 5]]
```

Till now I am good.

```
[1, 2, 5, [1, 2, 5]].shuffle!
#=> [5, 1, 2, [1, 2, 5]]
```

With above piece of code I have confusions. So below the questions came in my head:

- (a) Why `shuffle!` not worked recursively? As I expected that the output of the inner array `[1, 2, 5]` also will be shuffled. But not happened.
- (b) Why does `shuffle!` not shuffle the element array `[1, 2, 5]` , rather works only with the `1, 2, 5,` elements of the array `[1, 2, 5, [1, 2, 5]]` ? I thoght the output would come as `[[1, 2, 5],5, 1, 2]`. So  why the element array didn't change it's position,rather the normal elements did only?

***EDIT:***

Very interesting behavior it is showing:

```
a=[1,2,4]
#=> [1, 2, 4]
a<<[7,8]
#=> [1, 2, 4, [7, 8]]
a.shuffle!
#=> [[7, 8], 1, 4, 2]
a.shuffle!
#=> [4, 1, [7, 8], 2]
a.shuffle!
#=> [[7, 8], 2, 1, 4]
irb(main):006:0>
```

Does the shuffling really follow any order or its a random shuffling?

Answer (score 2):

a) `shuffle!` changes the order of objects in the array, this can be a collection of anything, so the method cannot assume that stuff inside also can or should be shuffled.

b) I don't really see how this question is different from a). Could you explain more what you think is confusing?

Comment: Looking at the documentation and source code (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shuffle), it suggests that the shuffling is random. What would you expect it to be?

Answer (score 2):

a) Why would `shuffle!` act recursively? It acts on the object it's passed, which in your example is an array of 4 items -- it shuffles them. The fact one of them is an array is neither here nor there, one of them could be a donkey for all it cares.

b) It does shuffle the array element, you should have tried your little IRB test more than once and you would have found that the array only didn't move per chance.

w/regards to your edit, what exactly are you trying to show here, I don't see any interesting behaviour at all? There is no pattern, shuffle is pseudo-random.

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed want arrays to be shuffled recursively, there is no problem:

```
# encoding: utf-8

a = [1,2,3]
a << [6,7,8]

class Array
  alias shuffle_orig shuffle
  def shuffle
    self.shuffle_orig.map { |e| e.respond_to?(:shuffle) ? e.shuffle : e }
  end
end


3.times do
  p a.shuffle
end
```

Which results in:

```
#⇒ [2, [8, 6, 7], 3, 1]
#⇒ [3, 1, [7, 6, 8], 2]
#⇒ [1, [8, 7, 6], 3, 2]
```

The bang version may be monckey-patched as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,4]
#=> [1, 2, 4]
a<<[7,8]

a.each_with_index do |element, index|

  puts "Index: #{index} element: #{element}"
end
```

with `a<<[7,8]` you append a new object into `a` array. 
This object will have a unique index.
Shuffle method uses this index for its purposes..

```
Index: 0 element: 1
Index: 1 element: 2
Index: 2 element: 4
Index: 3 element: [7, 8]
```

Appended array `[7,8]` is considered as 1 object and therefore its element inside will not be shuffled as the elements in array `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can imagine a situation where you need to shuffle the order of a set of arrays whose order is important.  In this case, shuffle is very handy, and if your needs change, it is easy to implement a recursive shuffle using the shuffle method.  If, however, Ruby included only a recursive shuffle, you would have to write the logic of the original, non-recursive shuffle method and could not implement a solution elegantly with the recursive shuffle method.  I think most languages prefer to have simple, versatile methods to more complex ones.